# Trying to print awk variable

Tags: awk

I am not much of an awk user, but after some Googling, determined it would work best for what I am trying to do...only problem is, I can't get it to work.  I'm trying to print out the contents of sudoers while inserting the server name ($i) and a comma before the sudoers entry as I'm directing it to a .csv file.

```
egrep '^[aA-zZ]|^[%]' //$i/etc/sudoers | awk -v var="$i" '{print "$var," $0}' | tee -a $LOG
```

This is the output that I get:

```
$var,unixpvfn   ALL = (root)NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/passwd

awk: no program given
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `... '{print var, $0}' ...`

Comment: I tried that, I get this:  
    awk: illegal field $(aappmab00001d01), name "var"
    input record number 1, file
    source line number 1
    awk: no program given

Comment: Note that @JamesBrown suggested `print var`, not `print $var`. Awk is not shell, it's syntax is much more similar to C than to shell. None of the answers you got explain the `awk: no program given` in your posted output so you may have another issue to uncover, probably related to using quotes incorrectly (unmatched or the wrong types of quotes) somewhere you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`egrep` is superfluous here. Just `awk`:

```
awk -v var="$i" '/^[[:alpha:]%]/{print var","$0}' //"$i"/etc/sudoers | tee -a "$LOG"
```

---

Btw, you may also use `sed`:

```
sed "/^[[:alpha:]%]/s/^/${i},/" //"$i"/etc/sudoers | tee -a "$LOG"
```

Comment: glad to see that it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `grep` and let `awk` do all the work:

```
awk -v svr="$i" '/^[aA-zZ%]/{print svr "," $0}' //$i/etc/sudoers 
    | tee -a $LOG
```

If you put things between `".."`, it means literal string, and variable won't be expanded in awk. Also, don't put `$` before a variable, it will indicate the column, not the variable you meant.

Comment: Right idea but `[aA-zZ]` means `a`, `Z`, and the characters between `A` and `z` which may be the empty set. I know the OP had that but it doesn't make sense and anyway - consider using `[:alpha:]`.